# How can I make connection by jdbc:mysql to siteground

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I would like to connect my own GUI project to siteground MySQL server by jdbc:mysql protocol .

The host name is `sgp39.siteground.asia` and the port is `3306`.

I tried using this command :

```
public void Connect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sgp39.siteground.asia:3306/dbdyyh2gyaltys", "username", "password");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

        }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

May I know what should I do next?
How can I find the correct path?

Comment: What exactly is your error message?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "this.this$0.con" is null
at loginSystem$2.actionPerformed(loginSystem.java:102)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)

Comment: Line102:
pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from userdata where username='" + getUserName+ "' and password='" + getPassword + "'    ");

rs = pst.executeQuery();

Comment: Clearly your connection is not instantiated. Check to see : 1- if you are able to access your database with an external client such as MySQL Workbench 2- if your connection string is valid 3- if your driver is correctly setup

Comment: I used an external phpMyAdmin php file tried  to make connection with the web hosting database and it is successful .

Answer (score 0):

I found this, maybe you use MySQL 8 dependency (com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver), try change dependency in pom.xml or change manual lib in your project to 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Comment: I tried and the similar error message occur .


Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "this.this$0.con" is null
 at loginSystem$2.actionPerformed(loginSystem.java:103)
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)

Comment: @Joseph In this case ```"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException:```, maybe you have error with UI, not jdbc

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, you can't create your connection, then in UI, in loginSystem will throw exception. Try use local MySQL, check port and connection string. If it success, maybe you should change connection string for your remote database

Comment: I can complete the connection by jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/databasename", "root", "".
The problem should be connection string, and I asked the customer service of siteground and they don't provide tech support for Java.

Comment: Check your config in remote. In my case, I used azure and they gave string look like: ```jdbc:mysql://data.azure.com:3306/databaseName?useSSL=true&requireSSL=false```

Comment: And use printStackTrace in catch to know what exactly error, in your case I only see AWT-EventQueue error not connection error

Comment: I set the printStackTrace in the program, and it show additional message:
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'username'@'pxx-xx.xx.xx.ne.jp' (using password: YES)
 at mysql.connector.java@8.0.25/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
 at mysql.connector.java@8.0.25/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
 at mysql.connector.java@8.0.25/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833)

Comment: That is a reason, your account don't have privilege or something like wrong password, and so on, use that username and password to login database in GUI app like MySQLWorkbench, make sure you can use that account before coding

Answer (score 0):

The reason is I only add the IPv6 address in the SiteGround webhosting manage site ,the solution is I have to entry IPv4 address.